# Filtro seleccionador en DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Hola buenas tardes amigos. ¿Alguien sabe como puede implementar un filtro para un DataGridView? Pero básicamente lo que quiero es que me posicione en la primera fila que coincida sin perder el orden del contenido DataGridView.

Implementé el siguiente código pero básicamente lo que hace es la búsqueda, pero me lista las coincidencias perdiendo los demás registros y a mi solo me interesaría que me posicionara en la primera coincidencia sin perder el orden del contenido.

```
private void TxtBuscador_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
          this.Indicador = new DataTable();
          (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = " Nombre LIKE '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%' ";
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message), "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes los registros, no debes volver a ponerle un `DataSource` distinto. Debes buscar en las filas existentes del `DataGridView`. El siguiente código se puede simplificar, pero ilustra la estrategia: recorrer las filas del `DataGridView`, buscar la coincidencia y seleccionar la fila en caso de que ocurra. Cambia "columna" por la columna donde debes buscar el valor.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   string valor = row.Cells["columna"].Value;
   string encontrar = '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%';
   bool encontrado= valor.Like(encontrar);
   if (encontrado){
      row.Selected = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta me sirvió bastante amigo al final modifique un poco tu código pero este fue el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Resultado

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
         string valor = row.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString();
         string encontrar = "" + txtBuscador.Text + "";
         bool encontrado = valor.StartsWith(encontrar);
         if (encontrado)
         {
             row.Selected = true;
             dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0];
              return;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Como no he notado que se haya marcado ninguna respuesta como aceptada, dejaré un pequeño ejemplo por si te sirve.

```
public void BuscarEnDatagrid(DataGridView datagrid, string nombre_columna, TextBox textbox)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid.Rows)
    {
        int fila = row.Index;
        string valor = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[nombre_columna].Value);

        if (valor.Contains(textbox.Text))
           datagrid.Rows[fila].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
        else
           datagrid.Rows[fila].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;

        //Si esta vacio el campo de busqueda quitar el sombreado
        if (textbox.Text == string.Empty)
           datagrid.Rows[fila].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Y para usarlo:

```
private void TxtBuscador_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
      BuscarEnDatagrid(dataGridView1, "Nombre", txtBuscador);
}
```

Lo que hace es resaltar las filas que contienen lo que escribes en tu `TextBox`, sin perder los demás datos, pero puedes modificar la lógica a tu gusto, solo es una muestra.